# Accounts with No Orders in Timeframe

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query where I get the results of what `Accounts` have had no `Orders` for a given `Business`.

So I want to filter on the `Business` level, and there can be multiple businesses and all have unique accounts to them.

The database relationship could basically be looked at like this:
[image: Database ER Diagram]

I've tried this with a test business account, however, I'm not getting the results I wanted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.name)
FROM Accounts AS A
LEFT JOIN `Token` AS T ON T.account_id = A.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders AS O WHERE O.account_id = A.id)
AND T.business_id = 1
```

I was also hoping I could just do a `WHERE` check on the Orders if business_id = 1, but that didn't give me anything different.

Comment: The parentheses in `SELECT DISTINCT(A.name)` are simply ignored. `SELECT DISTINCT` is not a function, it will apply to all columns you specify in the select clause (not just those you place in parentheses).

Comment: Some sample data (not as images) and the expected result would really assist here.

Comment: also, your title refers to timeframe, but there are no dates in the diagram or query

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the Token table in this query? If you only want accounts with no orders then you could do it like this:

```
SELECT A.name FROM Accounts A
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT O.id FROM Orders O WHERE O.account_id = A.id AND O.business_id = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can test this:

```
SELECT A.name
FROM Accounts AS A
LEFT JOIN Orders AS O ON A.id = O.account_id
LEFT JOIN Businesses AS B ON B.id = O.business_id
GROUP BY A.name
HAVING COUNT(O.id) = 0;
```